# Returning an actual Promise from an async function

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I understand that async functions natively return a Promise. I would like to know how to return another promise as the result of a resolved async function promise (nested Promise, so to speak). If it's not possible, I am interested in the reasons for this.

Below is some example code where some object properties are lost.

```js
function B() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve('B resolved'), 10);
   })
}

async function A() {
    const result = new Promise((resolve) => { setTimeout(() => resolve('A resolved'), 30); }); 
    result.test = 'test';
    result.b = await B();
    return result;
}

const a = A();
console.log('a.b', a.b); // expected undefined, correct
console.log('test1', a.test); // expected undefined, correct

a.then((a_data) => {
    console.log('a_data', a_data); // expected Promise constructed in A(), actually 'A resolved'
    console.log('a_data.b', a_data.b); // expected 'B resolved', actually undefined
    console.log('a_data.test', a_data.test); // expected 'test', actually undefined
 
    // this code expected to be allowed, but .then is not a member of a_data since it's not a promise
    // a_data.then((data) => {
    //     console.log(data); // expected 'A resolved'
 // });
});
```

I also understand that in most cases it would be better to wait for the Promise defined in A() to resolve before providing the result, however, this is not the answer I'm looking for.

The 'result' object returns as expected as long as it is not a Promise, otherwise the 'result' promise is resolved and the extra properties 'test' and 'b' are lost.

Comment: You're adding values to promise object, which when you call then just returns the resolved object not the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding them on promise object and when that get resolved it just returns the value returned from resolved function so you lost `test` and `b`, If you need `test` and `b` on value returned from promised object you need return them from resolve function.

```js
function B() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('B resolved'), 1000);
  })
}

async function A() {
  const result = new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve({
      test: "test",
      b:  B()
    }), 3000);
  });

  return result;
}

const a = A();
console.log('a.b', a.b); // expected undefined, correct
console.log('test1', a.test); // expected undefined, correct

a.then((a_data) => {
  console.log('a_data', a_data); // expected Promise constructed in A(), actually 'A resolved'
  console.log('a_data.b', a_data.b.then(v=> console.log(v))); // expected 'B resolved', actually undefined
  console.log('a_data.test', a_data.test); // expected 'test', actually undefined

  // this code expected to be allowed, but .then is not a member of a_data since it's not a promise
  // a_data.then((data) => {
  //      console.log(data); // expected 'A resolved'
  // });
});
```